# Ruby : cannot open a link that works in a web browser

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, open-uri

I am trying to get a picture from the site mangafox, the picture is displayed in the navigators but I keep getting errors whit Ruby

So far, I have tried this :

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'pp'

def get_page(link)
  page = nil
  begin
    page = open(link, 'User-Agent' => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}")
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.class.to_s
    puts e.message
  end
  return page
end

link = 'http://h.mfcdn.net/store/manga/9/14-116.0/compressed/Bleach-14-116[manga-rain]._manga_rain_bleach_ch116_01.jpg?token=24530ad3411b28ed7f5ef17f932e8713&ttl=1494853200'
# tried this after researching on internet because some characters are refused in links ( such as '[' or ']' )
link2 = link.gsub(/[\[\]]/) { '%%%s' % $&.ord.to_s(16) }.chomp

pp get_page(link)
pp get_page(link2)
```

but I get this output:

> URI::InvalidURIError
>   bad URI(is not URI?): http://h.mfcdn.net/store/manga/9/14-116.0/compressed/Bleach-14-116[manga-rain]._manga_rain_bleach_ch116_01.jpg?token=24530ad3411b28ed7f5ef17f932e8713&ttl=1494853200
>   nil
>   OpenURI::HTTPError
>   403 Forbidden
>   nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using OpenURI is fine in a pinch, but you'd be better served by a more robust networking library like Net::HTTP or Typhoeus:

```
response = Typhoeus.get('http://h.mfcdn.net/store/manga/9/14-116.0/compressed/Bleach-14-116[manga-rain]._manga_rain_bleach_ch116_01.jpg?token=24530ad3411b28ed7f5ef17f932e8713&ttl=1494853200')
response.body #=> binary image data
```

(Note: tested this before sharing — it loads fine)

Comment: it works perfectly thanks a lot.
Will have to look at the documentation for the error handling tho